# Beamer: how to keep an image at its location while using only to uncover text

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays, transition

This question is essentially the same as one of my [earlier one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424116/beamer-displaying-four-images-how-to-pre-allocate-space-for-the-first-image), except the only difference is that I am using "only" to change the text at the same location (i.e., [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109677/latex-beamer-how-to-uncover-formulas-text-at-a-location-of-an-ununcovered-fo)). In other words, I am destroying my earlier text as I go, and not adding new ones underneath the previous ones.

Since the text for the first "only" is shorter than the second "only", therefore the image will shift location. I would like for the image to remain at its location.

Here is an example
[image]

[image]

it may not be obvious but the second image is higher up than the first.

The code is here, can someone find a solution?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\title[Title]{Presentation}
\author{Sandro Botticelli}
\institute{Italy}
\date{1484}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{Venus}
    \caption{Nascita di Venere}
\end{figure}

\only<1>{In the centre the newly-born goddess Venus stands nude in a giant scallop shell. Its size is purely imaginary, and is also found in classical depictions of the subject. } 


\only<2>{Alternative identifications for the two secondary female figures involve those also found in the Primavera; the nymph held by Zephyr may be Chloris, a flower nymph he married in some versions of her story, and the figure on land may be Flora. Flora is generally the Roman equivalent of the Greek Chloris; in the Primavera Chloris is transformed into the figure of Flora next to her, following Ovid's Fasti, but it is hard to see that such a transformation is envisaged here.}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Just add `[t]` : `\begin{frame}[t]`.

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer

Comment: Third alternative: `overlayarea`

Comment: @samcarter : overlayarea was part of my answer's quote, but I couldn't put the code block properly. Now I found how to do it and updated my post.

Comment: @sztruks Oh, right. But to be fair, before your edit it was hard to overlook :)

Comment: @sztruks I always used `overlayarea` until samcarter taught me the `[t]` trick. I'd rather not go back to `overlayarea`....

Comment: @marmot I think this is a matter of taste. I prefer vertically centred slides. Note that I wouldn't use `overlayarea` neither. I suggest using `overprint`. Anyway, I think it would be good to have the two alternatives, so that each one can pick up according to his tastes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @marmot suggested in his comments, `\begin{frame}[t]` would do it. I think you should anyway use the `overprint` environment. Works also when your picture is not at the top.

From beameruserguide:

> The trouble with this approach [using `\only`] is that it may lead to slight, but annoying
>   differences in the heights of the lines, which may cause the whole frame to
>   “wobble” from slide to slide. This problem becomes much more severe if the
>   replacement text is several lines long.
>
> To solve this problem, you can use two environments: overlayarea and 
>   overprint. The first is more flexible, but less user-friendly.
>
> ```
>  \begin{overlayarea}{⟨area width⟩}{⟨area height⟩}
>  ⟨environment contents⟩
>  \end{overlayarea}
> ```
>
> Everything within the environment will be placed in a rectangular area of 
>   the specified size. The area will have the same size on all slides of a 
>   frame, regardless of its actual contents.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}
> \only<1>{Some text for the first slide.\\Possibly several lines long.}
> \only<2>{Replacement on the second slide.}
> \end{overlayarea}
> \begin{overprint}[⟨area width⟩]
>  ⟨environment contents⟩
> \end{overprint}
> ```
>
> The area width defaults to the text width.

Here is your MWE with `overprint`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title[Title]{Presentation}
\author{Sandro Botticelli}
\institute{Italy}
\date{1484}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{Venus}
    \caption{Nascita di Venere}
\end{figure}

\begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1>{In the centre the newly-born goddess Venus stands nude in a giant scallop shell. Its size is purely imaginary, and is also found in classical depictions of the subject. } 
    \onslide<2>{Alternative identifications for the two secondary female figures involve those also found in the Primavera; the nymph held by Zephyr may be Chloris, a flower nymph he married in some versions of her story, and the figure on land may be Flora. Flora is generally the Roman equivalent of the Greek Chloris; in the Primavera Chloris is transformed into the figure of Flora next to her, following Ovid's Fasti, but it is hard to see that such a transformation is envisaged here.}
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```